# How to get API Gateway to validate the pattern of HTTP query string parameters?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get API Gateway to do the above. See template at the bottom - there is a single `message` parameter, which I've tried to restrict to either `foo` or `bar` values, via specification of an `AWS::ApiGateway::Model` resource, bound to `Content-Type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Now APIGW will validate the *presence* of the `message` parameter -

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/1-0-0/hello?messag=foo"
{"message": "Missing required request parameters: [message]"}
```

But it doesn't seem to validate or restrict the *value* sent -

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/1-0-0/hello?message=whatever"
you sent 'whatever'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

---

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Outputs:
  PublicApiEndpoint:
    Value:
      Fn::Sub: https://${PublicApiRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${PublicApiStage}
Parameters:
  MemorySizeDefault:
    Default: '512'
    Type: String
  RuntimeVersion:
    Default: '3.8'
    Type: String
  TimeoutDefault:
    Default: '5'
    Type: String
Resources:
  HelloFunction:
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          def handler(event, context):
              message=event["queryStringParameters"]["message"]
              response="you sent '%s'" % message
              return {'statusCode': 200,
                      'headers': {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
                      'body': response}
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize:
        Ref: MemorySizeDefault
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - HelloFunctionRole
        - Arn
      Runtime:
        Fn::Sub: python${RuntimeVersion}
      Timeout:
        Ref: TimeoutDefault
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  HelloFunctionRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Policies:
      - PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Action:
            - logs:CreateLogGroup
            - logs:CreateLogStream
            - logs:PutLogEvents
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
          Version: '2012-10-17'
        PolicyName:
          Fn::Sub: hello-function-role-policy-${AWS::StackName}
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  HelloEndpointMethod:
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri:
          Fn::Sub:
          - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${arn}/invocations
          - arn:
              Fn::GetAtt:
              - HelloFunction
              - Arn
      RequestParameters:
        "method.request.querystring.message": true
      RequestValidatorId:
        Ref: HelloEndpointValidator
      RequestModels:
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": HelloEndpointModel
      ResourceId:
        Ref: HelloEndpointResource
      RestApiId:
        Ref: PublicApiRestApi
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  HelloEndpointPermission:
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Ref: HelloFunction
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        Fn::Sub: arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${PublicApiRestApi}/${PublicApiStage}/GET/hello
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  HelloEndpointResource:
    Properties:
      ParentId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - PublicApiRestApi
        - RootResourceId
      PathPart: hello
      RestApiId:
        Ref: PublicApiRestApi
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
  HelloEndpointValidator:
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: PublicApiRestApi
      ValidateRequestParameters: true
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
  HelloEndpointModel:
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: PublicApiRestApi
      ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      Name: HelloEndpointModel
      Schema:
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
        type: object
        properties:
          message:
            type: string
            pattern: "^((foo)|(bar))$"
        required:
          - message
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Model    
  PublicApiDeployment:
    DependsOn:
    - HelloEndpointMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: PublicApiRestApi
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
  PublicApiRestApi:
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: public-api-rest-api-${AWS::StackName}
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  PublicApiStage:
    Properties:
      DeploymentId:
        Ref: PublicApiDeployment
      RestApiId:
        Ref: PublicApiRestApi
      StageName: 1-0-0
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible - https://twitter.com/alexbdebrie/status/1603059764489252864?s=20&t=LI7OUEw9b5qxCIvkeP4AYQ